# Why Do I Receive Double Emails & Is there a way to echo a page link?

Tags: php, html, email

The html/php works great except I echo an entire html page which is horrible using heredocs. 
Also I am receiving one good email from the form but also a blank email at the same time when the end user is filling out the form and clicks the send button.
Heres My Mark Up

```js
<? php

/* Subject and email variables */

$emailsSubject = 'Customer Sent You A Message';
$webMaster = 'myemail@mydomain.com';


/* Gathering Data Variables - Whats in the form */

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

/*Security*/




/* What You Want To See In The Email Place Inbetween $body = <<<EOD  and EOD; */
$body = << < EOD

  < strong > Client: < /strong> $first_name $last_name
<br / >
  < br / >
  < strong > Phone: < /strong> $phone
<br / >
  < br / >
  < strong > Email: < /strong> $email
<br / >
  < br / >
  ______________________________________________ < br / >
  < br / >
  $message

EOD;

/* Headers is a tag containing the users email and how you want it to display in your email */

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers. = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

/* This is what sends the email */
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailsSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results Rendered as Html */
$theResults = << < EOD

  < !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < /head>
<body>
<div>This is my html content</div >
  < /body>
</html >



  EOD;
echo "$theResults";

?>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Form Begins-->
  <div id="form_content">
    <form action="contact_form.php" method="post" name="Contact Us">
      <br>

      <span id="sprytextfield1">
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextfield2">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextfield3">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"></span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextfield4">
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextarea1">
  <label for="message">Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">*</span></span>

      <br>
      <br>


      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn">
      <br>
      <br>


    </form>

    <!--Form Ends-->
  </div>

  <!--Form ID END-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "none", {
      validateOn: ["change"],
      minChars: 2
    });
    var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2", "none", {
      validateOn: ["change"],
      minChars: 2
    });
    var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3", "email", {
      validateOn: ["change"],
      minChars: 8
    });
    var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4", "phone_number", {
      format: "phone_custom",
      pattern: "000-000-0000",
      validateOn: ["change"],
      useCharacterMasking: true
    });
    var sprytextarea1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextarea("sprytextarea1", {
      validateOn: ["change"]
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to sent the email only if there is really content. Otherwise you get the empty email.

And then, you can mix PHP and HTML.

```
<? php

/* Subject and email variables */

$emailsSubject = 'Customer Sent You A Message';
$webMaster = 'myemail@mydomain.com';


/* Gathering Data Variables - Whats in the form */

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

/*Security*/

if (!$message) {
    echo 'You have to enter a message.';
    exit;
}



/* What You Want To See In The Email Place Inbetween $body = <<<EOD  and EOD; */
$body = << < EOD

  < strong > Client: < /strong> $first_name $last_name
<br / >
  < br / >
  < strong > Phone: < /strong> $phone
<br / >
  < br / >
  < strong > Email: < /strong> $email
<br / >
  < br / >
  ______________________________________________ < br / >
  < br / >
  $message

EOD;

/* Headers is a tag containing the users email and how you want it to display in your email */

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers. = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

/* This is what sends the email */
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailsSubject, $body, $headers);

?>
< !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < /head>
<body>
<div>This is my html content</div >
  < /body>
</html >
```

Comment: This is not the issue. I already have validation in place using java script and I want to be able to redirect the php to echo to a new html instead of using html in the php

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why my script was send duplicates, I just needed to remove the extra space in the end of the php script:

```html
<?php
/* Results Rendered as Html */
 $theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
My html content I wanted to display once the user clicked the submit button.
</body>
</html>
<!--The Problem was here ( I had to many spaces so I removed one and the duplicate blank email went away. )


EOD;
echo "$theResults";

?>
```

As for my other question how not to echo my entire HTML page but still get the same results I did this instead and it worked!

```html
<? php

/* Results Rendered as Html */
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/path/file.html");

?>
```

Not only did this work but it also kept the duplicate emails out of my inbox!